# Could using static Tasks like this lead to a memory leak?

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, reference, json.net, uwp

Would the following static C# Task lead to a memory leak? Please note that the JSON related methods are using [Newtonsoft.JSON.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

```
public static async Task<List<Result>> TMDBDiscover(string url)
{
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url))
            {
                using (Stream stream = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result)
                {
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                    {
                        List<Result> ResultList = new List<Result>();
                        string json = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
                        foreach (Result r in root.results)
                        {
                            ResultList.Add(r);
                        }
                        root = null;
                        json = "";
                        return ResultList;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Would calling this method from a page like this:

```
foreach (Result r in await TMDBDiscover("url"))
    listview.Items.Add(r)
```

create a reference to ResultList that doesn't get collected by GC? I say this because I've inspected the app's memory with Resharper's dotMemory tool, and some of the data contained in the ResultList appears to be left over when I navigate to another page.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no memory leak here. The task is not static - the task is *returned* from a static method. It's also not necessary to set `root` to `null` or `json` to the empty string.

On a side note, you shouldn't use `Result` here; use `await` instead.

Comment: Oh yeah, about setting root or json to null it was just a stupid test to figure out if that might have changed anything (it didn't). Also, sorry for my ignorance, but I'm quite a newbie to C#: What is the difference between a static class and a task returned from a static method?

Comment: In terms of memory leaks, a static *field* will stay in memory. A static method is just a method that you can call without having an instance of its containing class, like a function. A static class is a class that can only contain static members.